# What permission does a Presto CLI command inside a shell script require in order to be able to execute

Tags: shell, hadoop, oozie, presto, oozie-workflow

I have a oozie workflow which calls a shell script. The shell script calls a presto cli query.  If I execute the shell script from the putty terminal then everything works as expected

But when I run the Workflow an error is raised. I know the shell script itself is being called successfully as I can see my ECHO statement in the log fileas below

This script is stored inside the Hadoop File system

shell script :

```
#!/bin/bash 

echo Execute Presto Command
/home/hdfs/presto-cli --server 1.1.1.1:8080 --catalog hive --schema test --execute 'SELECT * from test limit 10'
```

However when the presto-cli command is called a "Permission Denied" error is raised

I can see in the Oozie GUI for the action that is running as my HDFS user so I am not sure what permission it refers to?

I read somewhere that you need to tell the workflow to run as the user who launched the workflow and not the YARN user. I added the env-var tag to my workflow action (see  below) but this didnt help either

My Workflow's action is below :

```
      <action name="Shell-Action">
    <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
              <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <configuration>
            <property>
          <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                      <value>${queueName}</value>
                  </property>
              </configuration>
              <exec>_myshell.sh</exec>
              <env-var>HADOOP_USER_NAME=${wf:user()}</env-var>                
              <file>/user/hdfs/scripts/myshell.sh</file>
          </shell>
          <ok to="end"/>
          <error to="fail"/>
      </action>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You may want to use `--user` option in presto cli. When we omit the option, the query will be executed by login username (=System.getProperty("user.name") in Java).

Comment: --user didnt help unfortunately. The only error that I can find is Exit Code 126 on the shell script which from what I can figure out means "Permission Denied". Is there a place that I can check the Presto Error log to see a more detailed error if it even got this far?

Comment: I think the error isn't produced from Presto. If the cause is Presto, you can get the detailed message with `--debug` option. Did you confirm whether shell script file permission is fine?

Comment: Yes. I did chmod +x on shell script and double checked it was applied. Also the echo command inside shell script works fine. Also calling the shell script from the putty command line works fine to. Its just when trying to run it through oozie workflow that I get error 126 when it gets to presto part of shell script. I can confirm that the #USER is the user I am wanting it to be as echoed this in shell script. Is it not perhaps and envirnoment setup, something present when logged via putty but not when oozie executes script?

Comment: Could you share the file status (shell script file & presto-cli) including owner and permission? Also, I would like you to share the actual entire command and the message what you tried.

Comment: I have managed to solve the problem. It was 2 fold. Firstly, as I know happens but didnt pick up on it at first each execution of the workflow was happening on a different data node. When I checked the application log files that was giving the Exit Code 126 error I didn't check any further. Per chance I happened to read a bit further into the log file and came across this : test.sh: line 5: /home/hdfs/presto-cli: Permission denied. The problem was that even although I had made the presto-cli executable I had to make each folder in the path executable, in this case the 'hdfs' folder

Comment: Secondly I had to do this on each data node as from the log file I can see now that each time I get the permission denied error its on a different data node. So the problem was purely to do with access rights per data node to the presto-cli

Comment: By the way, I would recommend you to join community Slack https://prestosql.io/slack.html.